# How do I put html in a JLabel in java?

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel

How do I use html tags in a JLabel in java?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: `JLabel label = new JLabel().setText("<html><tag>blah blah</tag></html>");`

Comment: This strikes me as a bad idea.

Comment: A very bad idea, indeed.

Comment: Why is this a bad idea? Its even documented in the Swing tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html

Comment: it is a quite effective way of doing simple formatting in your text areas...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To put html in a `JLabel`, you would make it look something like this

```
 JLabel label = new JLabel("<html><yourTagHere><yourOtherTagHere>this is your text</yourOtherTagHere></yourTagHere></html>");
```

Answer (score 8):

This will do the trick:

```
 String labelText ="<html><FONT COLOR=RED>Red</FONT> and <FONT COLOR=BLUE>Blue</FONT> Text</html>";
 JLabel coloredLabel =new JLabel(labelText);
```

Answer (score 5):

There are following ways

1. Using SetText method of JLabel Object

   `JLabel HTMLlabel = new JLabel().setText("<html><tag>blah blah</tag></html>");`
2. Passing String to JLable class Constructor.

   `JLabel HTMLlabel = new JLabel("<html><tag>blah blah</tag></html>");`
3. Using String and passing it to JLabel class Constructor similar to above example but using String.

   `String HTMLlabelStr = "<html><tag>blah blah</tag></html>";

   JLabel HTMLlabel = new JLabel(HTMLlabelStr);`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
JLabel whatever =
    new JLabel("<html><something>Put Stuff Here</something></html>");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JLabel myHTMLLabel =new JLabel("<html>");
myHTMLLabel.setText("<html><font color='green'>Hello World</font>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use this with all Swing buttons, menu items, labels, text panes, editor panes, tool tips, tabbed panes etc...

```
JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
pane.setContentType("text/html");

pane.setText("<html><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>");
```