# Is it possible to show Image object in a jTextEditor as HTML tag?

Tags: java, html, image

I have java.awt.Image img, And want to add it to myjTextEditor as HTML tag, the known way to imbed image by img src=.... , didnt work:

```
String Html="<img src=\""+thumb+"\"/><br/>";// thumb is an Image Object
myjTextEditor.setText(Html);
```

That code will work fine if thumb is a file... is it possible to do that? (i.e imbed Image object)??

Comment: are you persist in using textEditor? I think jLable can use html.
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635730/how-do-i-put-html-in-a-jlabel-in-java
JTextPane can also do the similar thing.

Comment: @Terry Zhao, I just tomorrow convert from jlabel to Jtexteditor :))  but I know that Jtexteditor supports HTML very well, I said : That code will work fine if thumb is a file

Answer (score 1):

Well if you can base64 encode thumb data you can use like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
 9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

The section after image/png;base64, is base64 encoded binary image data.

Comment: thak you regulus but this :
 'String Html="<img src=\"data:image/jpg;base64,"+thumb+ "\" />" ; '
does Not work

Comment: OK, I found that saving the image to file is less complex and do the work, thank u @regulus