# Colouring specific letters in a String?

Tags: java, string, swing

I am trying to change the colour of all 'A's in the string to green and all 'Z's in the string to red colour. I have a string as:

```
String input = "LENGTH OF THIS STRING IS GREATER THAN ZERO";
```

I want to output it on the screen (in SWING, see comments) with all letters 'A' colored to green and 'Z' colored to red.

Comment: Is this a Swing application you're writing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to color System.out.println output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448858/how-to-color-system-out-println-output)

Comment: yes, it is a swing application in java

Comment: Show us your code you tried!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448858/how-to-color-system-out-println-output

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074428/how-can-i-set-each-character-to-a-different-color-background-color-in-a-jtextpan

Comment: Ok, so this is swing. You should have told from the start. You should post the code you already have because there are different ways to draw text in Swing.

Comment: In that case, you can probably find the answer you want in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6635730)

Comment: I haven't written any specific code yet. I have been trying to find any way...but only found html codes for it, which I could not comprehend. I wanted something in java language, so need help

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Swing component (JLabel, JButton, J...) then you should use some HTML in your Swing component.

Here is an example from [official Swing documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html):

```
button = new JButton("<html><b><u>T</u>wo</b><br>lines</html>");
```

So you can do whatever you want with your text !

I guess this is not the case, but you can also want to 'draw' your text in Canvas, then you should read the [documentation about Java2D API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/index.html)