# Swing get user input from a pop up table

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a popup user input getter that will show a table like field with multiple text lines.

As an example, I would want a window with 10 rows of text lines and a label to the left side saying what each entry is, and would want to populate it with some default value.

Kind of like [this](https://www.thedataschool.co.uk/content/images/wordpress/2020/09/InputOutputMulti.png) but just the left table and I can modify the white boxes and press confirm.

Is this possible in Swing?

Comment: Yes it is. I would make a `JPanel` with the required input components on. Then you could add that to a `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane`

Comment: Use a `JTable` to display the data. You can control which columns are editable.

Comment: Refer to [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) which is part of Oracle's Java tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Refer to How to Use Tables [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html] which is part of Oracle's Java tutorials. –
> @Abra

With this tutorial, I was able to see most of what you are looking for, but it is asking for the names to go on the top with the Object Array like so:

```
// [rows][columns]
JTable(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames)
```

It appears that may be the only way to set names in a JTable (column instead of by row). You mentioned **a label to the left side saying what each entry is** and that gave me the idea of using the html tag as shown here:

> [How do I put html in a JLabel in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635730/how-do-i-put-html-in-a-jlabel-in-java#6635733) -- *NOTE* this syntax is not exclusive to the JLabel

And because I don't see it on that page, I'll include one more piece of information. In order to have multiple lines, you will need to use `<br>` (break) like so:

```
<html><tagHere>"first row"<br>"second row"<br>"third row"</tagHere></html>
```

Or you could set the table one column wider than you need, set the contents for `rowData[rowIndex][0]` to be the description, and keep that from being edited.